# WDQS - Query is malformed

Tags: sparql, wdqs

I started today with WDQS, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious

I'm trying to get all items that are an instance of Q9143 (programing language)

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT ?item
WHERE 
{
 ?item wd:Q9143
}
```

> Error: Query is malformed: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 6, column
> 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements in your WHERE clause must be triples so include a variable for the property.

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT ?item
WHERE 
{
 ?item ?prop wd:Q9143 .
}
```

The sample query at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Informatics/Programming_Language/list might give you some ideas.

Comment: the TO was asking for instance of relation, thus the property should be `wdt:P31`